How to create an editable DataTable in Shiny with tooltips and always-visible input fields?
I would like to display a data table in an R Shiny dashboard using DT, where the user can enter measurement values in the "Value" column. All other columns should not be editable. The process of entering a value in the "Value" column should work without needing to double-click on the cell. Is it possible to have the input field permanently displayed by default in all cells of the "Value" column?
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(
  Param = c("FVC", "FEV1", "FEV1/FVC ratio"),
  Tooltip = c("forced vital capacity", "forced expiratory volume exhaled in the first second", "tiffeneau index"),
  Unit = c("l", "l", "%"),
  Value = c(NA, NA, NA)
)

data

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    DTOutput("table")
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data,
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        paging = FALSE,
        ordering = FALSE
      ),
      selection = 'none',
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(0, 1, 2)))
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
}

# Shiny-App starten
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Take a look at the rhandsontable package for editing data tables https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/

Then, the process of entering a value: Is the tooltip requirement connected to the always shown input fields or shall this work separately? I'm asking because of Then. Also, there is a chance that this question gets closed because it needs more focus, you have several requirements here. When you always show the input fields (what is not very trivial on its own) you get additional topics if you e.g. want to sort or filter the table, see Live DOM ordering. Is the Age column in the table displayed in the link like you want it here?

Dear Jan, yes, the Age column in the Live DOM ordering example is exactly what I am looking for. However, the table does not need to be sortable by any column.

@Ifeanyi Idiaye: As far as I can see, the cell needs to be double-clicked for editing in the rhandsontable package as well. The package looks interesting anyway.

Change the Value column in your above example to Value = paste0('<input type="text" style = "width: 100%" id="val_', 1:3, '">') and add the argument escape = 3 in datatable(). Does this yield what you would like to have and is working for your application? If so, I can write an answer, if not, what's missing?

Great, it works wonderfully! How can I retrieve the data from the "Value" column when I generate the text fields this way? And is it possible to populate the fields through the script as well?

Concerning the first question do you mean that if the user enters a value, you e.g. want to trigger an event where you get the column values to an R object? Or what is your goal with "Retrieve"? And for the second question, is your goal that with "populate" you want to set default values into the inputs which you define directly inside the R script when creating the table?

I’m wondering if, with the approach you suggested (Value = paste0('<input type="text" style = "width: 100%" id="val_', 1:3, '" oninput="Shiny.setInputValue(\'val_', 1:3, '\', this.value)">')), I can also read and modify the values in the "Value" column as I would in a normal DT. I would like to use the values in the "Value" column elsewhere in the dashboard for calculations and later write them to a CSV file. But I can also try it out later to see if it works.

Below is a modified version of your example where the functionality is working that if you populate the inputs via the "Select dummy data" option, these values get recognized by shiny. The reason why this is not working in your example is that you created the inputs using oninput="Shiny.setInputValue(...)", but this never gets triggered when the user does not type something into the input. So shiny does not know the values in such a case.
Below I added a session$sendCustomMessage which sends the list of values to JS after populating the inputs and there triggers a Shiny.setInputValue on each of them. Then shiny knows them and also if the user changes some of the values, your previously defined Shiny.setInputValue lets shiny know the updated values.
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

# Data frame skeleton without data
data <- data.frame(
  Param = c("FVC", "FEV1", "FEV1/FVC ratio"),
  Tooltip = c("forced vital capacity", "forced expiratory volume exhaled in the first second", "tiffeneau index"),
  Unit = c("l", "l", "%"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("setCreatedInputs",
      function(message) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(message)) {
          Shiny.setInputValue(key, value);
        }
      })')),
    tabBox(
      id = "tabs",
      width = 12,
      tabPanel(
        "Input",
        selectInput("inputType", "Select Dummy Data:", choices = c("Empty", "Obstruction", "Restriction")),
        DTOutput("table")
      ),
      tabPanel("Output", verbatimTextOutput("outputText"))
    ),
    actionButton("createButton", "Create")
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Function to fill the data table with dummy data."
  updateTable <- function(inputType) {
    values <- switch(inputType,
                     "Empty" = list("", "", ""),
                     "Obstruction" = list("2.5", "1.8", "72.0"),
                     "Restriction" = list("3.2", "2.9", "90.6"))
    
    data$Value <- paste0('<input type="text" style="width: 100%" id="val_', 1:3, 
                         '" value="', values, 
                         '" oninput="Shiny.setInputValue(\'val_', 1:3, '\', this.value)">')
    
    names(values) <- paste0("val_", 1:length(values))

    session$sendCustomMessage("setCreatedInputs", message = values)
    
    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        data,
        options = list(
          dom = 't',
          paging = FALSE,
          ordering = FALSE
        ),
        selection = 'none',
        rownames = FALSE,
        escape = FALSE,  # Set escape to FALSE to allow HTML input fields
        editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(0, 1, 2)))
      )
    }, server = FALSE)
  }
  
  # Create Initial Data Table with Empty Text Fields
  observe({
    updateTable("Empty")
  })
  
  # Update the Data Table when the dropdown value is changed
  observeEvent(input$inputType, {
    updateTable(input$inputType)
  })
  
  # Update the output panel when the create button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$createButton, {
    # Extract and format values
    values <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {
      as.numeric(input[[paste0("val_", i)]])
    })
    
    # Check the type and structure of the values
    if (is.list(values) || any(is.na(values))) {
      # Display an error message if values is a list or contains NA values
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Error",
        "The data input is incorrect. Please check the inputs and try again.",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
    } else {
      # Format values to two decimal places
      formattedValues <- formatC(values, format = "f", digits = 2)
      
      # Combine parameters and formatted values
      outputText <- paste(data$Param, ":", formattedValues, data$Unit, collapse = ", ")
      
      output$outputText <- renderText({
        outputText
      })
      
      # Switch to the Output tab
      updateTabItems(session, "tabs", "Output")
    }
  })
}

# Shiny-App starten
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

